# multipage tables with ctable package

Tags: tables, page-breaking, ctable

Does anybody know if it is possible to have a multipage table with the package `ctable` (I know that it is possible with `longtable`)?

My code is the following:

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{ctable}

    \begin{document}
    \ctable[
    caption = Data Definitions and Sources,
    label = data,
    sideways
    ]
    {>{\bfseries}l p{0.3\columnwidth} c  c  p{0.3\columnwidth}}
    {
    }
    { \FL
    ....
    }
    \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. Could you reduce your example only with the needed packages?

Comment: `\ctable` makes a floating object; you need `longtable` for this application.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the `ctable` input syntax and easily switch between `tabularx` based formatting and `longtable` based formatting you could do something like the following which adds a `long` key to `ctable`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter



\newif\if@ctbl@long
\define@key{ctbl}{long}[]{\@ctbl@longtrue}

\long\def\foo#1\sbox#2!!{%
\long\expandafter\def\csname\string\ctable\endcsname[##1]##2##3##4{%
#1\if@ctbl@long\ctbl@long\fi\sbox#2}}



\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\foo
\csname\string\ctable\endcsname[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}!!


\def\ctbl@long\fi\sbox#1#2#3\@ctblend{\fi
\ctbl@@long#2%
}


\long\def\ctbl@@long#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
\ctbl@@@long#6%
}

\def\ctbl@@@long#1\begin#2#3#4\end#5{%
\def\@tempa{#5}%
\def\@tempb{tabular}%
\ifx\@tempa\@tempb\else\show\@tempa\ERROR\fi
\begin{longtable}{#3}%
\caption{\@ctblcaption\ifx\@ctbllabel\empty\else\label{\@ctbllabel}\fi}%
\endfirsthead
\caption*{\@ctblcaption\space(continued)}%
\endhead
#4\end{longtable}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ctable[
caption = Data Definitions and Sources,
label = data,
long
]
{>{\bfseries}l p{0.3\columnwidth} c  c  p{0.3\columnwidth}}
{
}
{ \FL
a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\
a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\
a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\
a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\
a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\
a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c\\
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Wybo Dekker: For your consideration: I'd love to see this as a regular option in the `ctable`-Package, precisely to be able to switch easily from one layout to the other! Preferably together with further options (`ctable`-style) to handle `tablehead`s and `-tails` etc. This would finally make `ctable` the _one_ solution as an interface to all table-packages I've ever needed...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I have just found the answer to a related question and it is the following:

The package doesn't provide such a possibility. The package uses minipage which makes it difficult to change the internal code. However I think switching to longtable isn't very hard.