# Setting up multiple-page table with table notes in apa6 document with longtable, threeparttable and threeparttablex

Tags: tables, longtable, apa6

I am working on an `apa6` document and need to place a multiple-page table with table notes (not footnotes). I thought the best way to achive that is using `longtable` `threeparttable`and `threeparttablex` packages. However in the `apa6` documentation it is said that threeparttable is loaded automatically, and about `longtable`:

> longtable: If you must use long tables (exceeding one page in length)
>   try this option [of apa6 doc cls, see MWE - entne] (but it may not work in all contexts). Do not load longtable
>   yourself because of precedence requirements with the endfloat package. Copy
>   the file APAendfloat.cfg from the “config” folder of your apa installation
>   to the working folder of your document (not in your texmf tree), and rename it to endfloat.cfg so that endfloat will recognize it. The supplied
>   APAendfloat.cfg file will also be necessary in conjunction with rotating
>   package (and its \sideways command) to produce rotated tables.

I followed these instructions. Nothing is said about `threeparttablex` there, though.

Now, the code I built results in the table itself (with notes) being set up correctly, but not where it should be placed in the document. It is placed at the very end of it. I figured out that this depends on the `endfloat.cfg` I copied in the directory following the instructions above (see block quote above). If I delete it from the directory, the table is in correct position. Also, if I, against instructions, load `longtable` not as a class option, but as a regular package, the table is in correct position, too, wether `endfloat.cfg` being in the directory or not.

Here is my working example:

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,a4paper,noextraspace,donotrepeattitle,longtable]{apa6} % 12 pt., doppelter Zeilenabstand usw.

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % für ä,ö,ü,Ä,Ö,Ü,ß usw.

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % für exakte Darstellung von Umlauten wie Ä

\usepackage{lipsum}           % Dummy-Text
\setlipsumdefault{8}          % Standard-Einstellung: Verwendung nur eines Lipsum-Paragraphs (in diesem Fall des achten)

\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}      % linksbündige Tabellen (longtable)

\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{threeparttablex}


%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ von apa6.cls automatisch geladene Packages
% booktabs, etoolbox, lmodern, threeparttable



%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Scriptsize (ca. 8pt) Für Anmerkungen in Tabellen
\makeatletter 
\g@addto@macro\TPT@defaults{\scriptsize} 
\makeatother
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

\title{Anxiety}
\shorttitle{ABM}
\renewcommand{\rheadname}{Kolumnentitel}     % Running head übersetzt

\author{\null Peter Pan}  

\affiliation{
\null
Universität

Fachbereich 
}   

\abstract{Theoretischer Hintergrund}




\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage{\section{Methode}}

\appendix
\section{Wortpaare}

\begin{ThreePartTable}

\begin{TableNotes} % <— here: TableNotes instead of tablenotes

\textit{Anmerkungen.} Schriftgröße 8pt \lipsum

\end{TableNotes} % <— also here: TableNotes instead of table notes

\begin{longtable}{l r r @{\hskip 0.5in} l r r}           % @{\hskip 0.5in} stellt den Abstand zwischen den entsprechenden Spalten ein (in 1 inch=2.54cm)

\toprule

\multicolumn{3}{c}{Liste 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Liste 2} \\   \midrule

krankheitsassoziiert & \% & WL & neutral & \% & WL \\[0.5ex]   \midrule

\endfirsthead

\caption*{Wortpaare (Fortsetzung)} \\

\toprule

\multicolumn{3}{c}{Liste 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Liste 2} \\   \midrule

krankheitsassoziiert & \% & WL & neutral & \% & WL \\[0.5ex]   \midrule

\endhead

\midrule

\endfoot

\bottomrule

\insertTableNotes

\endlastfoot

Schlaganfall          &  5.53           &     12        &   Schreibtisch                &       7.30        &   12    \\
Hirntumor             &  0.25       &        9      &   Klappstuhl                  &       0.21        &   10      \\
Leberversagen         &  0.07       &     13        &   Beistelltisch               &       0.07        &   13      \\
Magentumor          &  0.01     &       10      &   Schlafsofa                  &       0.03    &   10      \\
Knochentumor          &  0.02       &       12      &   Schlafsessel                &       0.02    &   12      \\
Lungenentzündung      &  2.19           &       16      &   Kleiderschrank          &       1.25        &   14      \\  
Prostatakrebs         &  0.86       &       13      &   Kronleuchter                &       0.54        &   12      \\
Kammerflimmern      &  0.17         &       13      &   Bettvorleger                &       0.14        &   12      \\
Herzversagen          &  1.69           &       12      &   Bilderrahmen                &       0.77        &   12      \\
Tuberkulose         &  1.59         &       11      &   Küchentisch                 &       0.89        &   11      \\
Brustkrebs          &  3.45         &       10      &   Garderobe                       &       3.63        &    9      \\
Infektion             &  3.83           &        9      &   Schublade                       &       5.08        &    9      \\
Kehlkopfkrebs         &  0.14       &       13      &   Kleiderhaken                &       0.13        &   12      \\
Keuchhusten         &  0.32         &       11      &   Fensterbrett                &       0.44        &   12      \\  
Blasenkrebs         &  0.10         &       11      &   Wandschrank                 &       0.16        &   11      \\
Arterienverkalkung  &  0.17         &       18      &   Handtuchhalter          &       0.07    &   14      \\
Nierenversagen      &  0.50         &       14      &   Kerzenständer               &       0.52        &   13      \\
Blutvergiftung      &  0.34         &       14      &   Küchenschrank               &       0.36        &   13      \\
Diabetes              &  5.99           &        8      &   Teppich                         &       7.74        &    7      \\
Epilepsie             &  0.91           &        9      &   Sitzkissen                  &       0.47        &   10      \\  
Darmkrebs             &  1.19       &        9      &   Bettdecke                       &       0.57        &    9      \\ 
Hautkrebs             &  1.17           &        9      &   Barhocker                       &       0.53        &    9      \\
Herzinsuffizienz      &  0.21       &       16      &   Fernsehsessel               &       0.26        &   13      \\
Vorhofflimmern      &  0.18         &       14      &   Schaukelstuhl               &       0.23        &   13      \\
Blutkrebs             &  0.39       &        9      &   Tischdecke                  &       0.32        &   10      \\
Herzinfarkt         &  6.58         &       11      &   Fernseher                       &    12.78      &    9      \\
Typhus              &  0.66         &        6      &   Vitrine                         &       2.14        &    7      \\
Parkinson             &  1.52           &        9      &   Papierkorb                  &       1.21        &   10      \\
Bronchitis          &  1.09         &       10      &   Kopfkissen                  &       0.55        &   10      \\
Tollwut             &  1.18         &        7      &   Matratze                        &       1.56        &    8      \\
Osteoporose         &  1.98         &       11      &   Teppichboden                &       1.08        &   12      \\
Vergiftung          &  1.30         &       10      &   Hängematte                  &       0.74        &   10      \\
Asthma              &  2.49         &        6      &   Laptop                          &       3.97        &    6      \\
Hepatitis             &  2.35           &        9      &   Badewanne                       &       2.85        &    9      \\
Bluthochdruck         &  2.36           &       13      &   Waschmaschine               &       2.63        &   13      \\
Leukämie                        &    2.66           &        8      &   Backofen                        &       2.21        &    8      \\
Lungenkrebs                 &  1.45         &       11      &   Spülmaschine                &       0.56        &   12      \\
Hirnhautentzündung  &  0.62         &       18      &   Kaffeemaschine          &       0.99        &   14      \\
Herzstillstand          &    0.97       &       14      &   Tiefkühltruhe               &       0.57        &   13      \\
Vogelgrippe                 &  3.79         &       11      &   Kühlschrank                 &       5.05        &   11      \\  
Tumor                               &    2.33           &        5      &   Lampe                               &       3.60        &    5      \\  
Hirnblutung                 &    0.34       &       11      &   Bücherregal                 &       0.45        &   11      \\  
Demenz                          &    4.05           &        6      &   Sessel                          &       5.15        &    6      \\  
Hirnschlag                  &    0.33       &       10      &   Schrankwand                 &       0.21        &   11      \\
Geschwür                        &    0.20       &        8      &   Stehlampe                       &       0.16        &    9      \\  
Grippe                          &    8.92         &      6      &   Vorhang                         &       9.02        &    7      \\
Aids                                &    9.60           &        4      &   Stuhl                               &       9.70        &    5      \\
Hodenkrebs                  &    0.16       &       10      &   Wäschekorb                  &       0.18        &   10      \\  [10pt] \midrule
M  & {1.84} & 10.60 & \multicolumn{2}{r}{2.06} & 10.38 \\
SD & {2.24} &  3.15 & \multicolumn{2}{r}{2.93} &  2.39 \\

\end{longtable}

\end{ThreePartTable}

\section{Leitfaden}

\section{Instruktionen}

\end{document}
```

Edit 1:

Well, in the meantime I found [this Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88566/34092) about doing multiple-page tables with `ctable`package. But I think there is no possibility to include subcaptions for page continuation with this. Also I am not sure if `ctable`is the best choice for doing all tables (you can't use it with `threeparttable` at the same time due to `\tnote` command).

Edit 2:

The first problem about table notes is solved thanks to the first answer. But I still encounter a significant problem with the positioning of the table in the document. I edited my explanations above. Second, I edited a modified MWE putting the table in appendix A and add appendix pages B and C after it, so that it doesn't come last in the document. Try the `endfloat.cfg`and package loading options I mentioned above to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

With `threeparttablex`you have to use `TableNotes` instead of `tablenotes`:

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,a4paper,noextraspace,donotrepeattitle,longtable]{apa6} % 12 pt., doppelter Zeilenabstand usw.

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % für ä,ö,ü,Ä,Ö,Ü,ß usw.

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % für exakte Darstellung von Umlauten wie Ä

\usepackage{lipsum}           % Dummy-Text
\setlipsumdefault{8}          % Standard-Einstellung: Verwendung nur eines Lipsum-Paragraphs (in diesem Fall des achten)

\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}      % linksbündige Tabellen (longtable)

\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{threeparttablex}


%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ von apa6.cls automatisch geladene Packages
% booktabs, etoolbox, lmodern, threeparttable



%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Scriptsize (ca. 8pt) Für Anmerkungen in Tabellen
\makeatletter 
\g@addto@macro\TPT@defaults{\scriptsize} 
\makeatother
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

\title{Anxiety}
\shorttitle{ABM}
\renewcommand{\rheadname}{Kolumnentitel}     % Running head übersetzt

\author{\null Peter Pan}  

\affiliation{
\null
Universität

Fachbereich 
}   

\abstract{Theoretischer Hintergrund}




\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{ThreePartTable}

\begin{TableNotes} % <— here: TableNotes instead of tablenotes

\textit{Anmerkungen.} Schriftgröße 8pt \lipsum

\end{TableNotes} % <— also here: TableNotes instead of table notes

\begin{longtable}{l r r @{\hskip 0.5in} l r r}           % @{\hskip 0.5in} stellt den Abstand zwischen den entsprechenden Spalten ein (in 1 inch=2.54cm)

\toprule

\multicolumn{3}{c}{Liste 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Liste 2} \\   \midrule

krankheitsassoziiert & \% & WL & neutral & \% & WL \\[0.5ex]   \midrule

\endfirsthead

\caption*{Wortpaare (Fortsetzung)} \\

\toprule

\multicolumn{3}{c}{Liste 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Liste 2} \\   \midrule

krankheitsassoziiert & \% & WL & neutral & \% & WL \\[0.5ex]   \midrule

\endhead

\midrule

\endfoot

\bottomrule

\insertTableNotes

\endlastfoot

Schlaganfall          &  5.53           &     12        &   Schreibtisch                &       7.30        &   12    \\
Hirntumor             &  0.25       &        9      &   Klappstuhl                  &       0.21        &   10      \\
Leberversagen         &  0.07       &     13        &   Beistelltisch               &       0.07        &   13      \\
Magentumor          &  0.01     &       10      &   Schlafsofa                  &       0.03    &   10      \\
Knochentumor          &  0.02       &       12      &   Schlafsessel                &       0.02    &   12      \\
Lungenentzündung      &  2.19           &       16      &   Kleiderschrank          &       1.25        &   14      \\  
Prostatakrebs         &  0.86       &       13      &   Kronleuchter                &       0.54        &   12      \\
Kammerflimmern      &  0.17         &       13      &   Bettvorleger                &       0.14        &   12      \\
Herzversagen          &  1.69           &       12      &   Bilderrahmen                &       0.77        &   12      \\
Tuberkulose         &  1.59         &       11      &   Küchentisch                 &       0.89        &   11      \\
Brustkrebs          &  3.45         &       10      &   Garderobe                       &       3.63        &    9      \\
Infektion             &  3.83           &        9      &   Schublade                       &       5.08        &    9      \\
Kehlkopfkrebs         &  0.14       &       13      &   Kleiderhaken                &       0.13        &   12      \\
Keuchhusten         &  0.32         &       11      &   Fensterbrett                &       0.44        &   12      \\  
Blasenkrebs         &  0.10         &       11      &   Wandschrank                 &       0.16        &   11      \\
Arterienverkalkung  &  0.17         &       18      &   Handtuchhalter          &       0.07    &   14      \\
Nierenversagen      &  0.50         &       14      &   Kerzenständer               &       0.52        &   13      \\
Blutvergiftung      &  0.34         &       14      &   Küchenschrank               &       0.36        &   13      \\
Diabetes              &  5.99           &        8      &   Teppich                         &       7.74        &    7      \\
Epilepsie             &  0.91           &        9      &   Sitzkissen                  &       0.47        &   10      \\  
Darmkrebs             &  1.19       &        9      &   Bettdecke                       &       0.57        &    9      \\ 
Hautkrebs             &  1.17           &        9      &   Barhocker                       &       0.53        &    9      \\
Herzinsuffizienz      &  0.21       &       16      &   Fernsehsessel               &       0.26        &   13      \\
Vorhofflimmern      &  0.18         &       14      &   Schaukelstuhl               &       0.23        &   13      \\
Blutkrebs             &  0.39       &        9      &   Tischdecke                  &       0.32        &   10      \\
Herzinfarkt         &  6.58         &       11      &   Fernseher                       &    12.78      &    9      \\
Typhus              &  0.66         &        6      &   Vitrine                         &       2.14        &    7      \\
Parkinson             &  1.52           &        9      &   Papierkorb                  &       1.21        &   10      \\
Bronchitis          &  1.09         &       10      &   Kopfkissen                  &       0.55        &   10      \\
Tollwut             &  1.18         &        7      &   Matratze                        &       1.56        &    8      \\
Osteoporose         &  1.98         &       11      &   Teppichboden                &       1.08        &   12      \\
Vergiftung          &  1.30         &       10      &   Hängematte                  &       0.74        &   10      \\
Asthma              &  2.49         &        6      &   Laptop                          &       3.97        &    6      \\
Hepatitis             &  2.35           &        9      &   Badewanne                       &       2.85        &    9      \\
Bluthochdruck         &  2.36           &       13      &   Waschmaschine               &       2.63        &   13      \\
Leukämie                        &    2.66           &        8      &   Backofen                        &       2.21        &    8      \\
Lungenkrebs                 &  1.45         &       11      &   Spülmaschine                &       0.56        &   12      \\
Hirnhautentzündung  &  0.62         &       18      &   Kaffeemaschine          &       0.99        &   14      \\
Herzstillstand          &    0.97       &       14      &   Tiefkühltruhe               &       0.57        &   13      \\
Vogelgrippe                 &  3.79         &       11      &   Kühlschrank                 &       5.05        &   11      \\  
Tumor                               &    2.33           &        5      &   Lampe                               &       3.60        &    5      \\  
Hirnblutung                 &    0.34       &       11      &   Bücherregal                 &       0.45        &   11      \\  
Demenz                          &    4.05           &        6      &   Sessel                          &       5.15        &    6      \\  
Hirnschlag                  &    0.33       &       10      &   Schrankwand                 &       0.21        &   11      \\
Geschwür                        &    0.20       &        8      &   Stehlampe                       &       0.16        &    9      \\  
Grippe                          &    8.92         &      6      &   Vorhang                         &       9.02        &    7      \\
Aids                                &    9.60           &        4      &   Stuhl                               &       9.70        &    5      \\
Hodenkrebs                  &    0.16       &       10      &   Wäschekorb                  &       0.18        &   10      \\  [10pt] \midrule
M  & {1.84} & 10.60 & \multicolumn{2}{r}{2.06} & 10.38 \\
SD & {2.24} &  3.15 & \multicolumn{2}{r}{2.93} &  2.39 \\

\end{longtable}

\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Now the result is as desired, i.e. below the table and in the same width:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, shame on me for not getting that. I thought I had copied the main code from the package documentation... unfortunately, there is still a significant problem with table positioning. I edited my whole topic about that. would be glad if you or somebody else could have a look.

Comment: Don’t use `endfloat.cfg`, if the table is in the correct place without it.

Comment: Hm so you think you don't have to use it? I am not really getting what that file is about and if it is necessary, but as long there is no better solution I'll go without that cfg. Thanks so far!

Comment: The config file adds support for `longtable` to `endfloat`, which is the reason why your table gets relocated to the end. This means, that you do not want to use `endfloat` and as a consequence do not need `endfloat.cfg`. You could set the class option `floatsintext` --- it didn’t change a thing when I tried it, but perhaps it makes you feel better . . .

Comment: I thought that `endfloat` is responsible for putting tables and figures after the references. However I expected, that they would be placed before the appendix. I need to have my tables and figures in a separate section after the references but before the appendix. But I put longtables always in the appendix. This longtable is the first table I created so far so I will see if the placing of the other tables and figures works. But as far as I understand that issue, it will, as long as I don't place a longtable prior to the appendix.