# Inclusion of a landscape multipage table in an apa6 class document

Tags: longtable, tabu, apa6

I have question concerning the inclusion of a landscape multipage table in an apa6 class document.

The example below is working fine (apa6 class is not used):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtabu}{XXX} 
\caption{test} \\
\hline
Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
\hline
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\ 
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    \hline

\end{longtabu}
 \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

However, If I change to the apa6 class in manuscript mode I get a bunch of errors

```
Line 36 Misplaced \cr \end{longtabu}
Line 36 Misplaced \cr \end{longtabu}
Line 36 Misplaced \cr \end{longtabu}
Line 36 Undefined control sequence \end{longtabu}
Line 37 Undefined control sequence \end{landscape}
```

this script gives me trouble:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtabu}{XXX} 
\caption{test} \\
\hline
Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
\hline
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\ 
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    \hline

\end{longtabu} % line 36
\end{landscape}    % line 37

\end{document}
```

I'm guessing endfloat might have something to do with my issues, or the fact that I load 'longtable', but I don't know the exact issues or how to solve them. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And your question is why doesn't this work with the `apa6` class? It might be better to post the non-working example as commented parts of the example document. In particular, the `apa6` class has special warnings about using `longtable`.  See also [Setting up multiple-page table with table notes in apa6 document with longtable, threeparttable and threeparttablex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136393)

Comment: You said you had a question but didn't say what the question is (I tried changing `article` to `apa6` and it worked as far as I can see)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm sorry you are correct, the question indeed is how to get it working in the apa6 class? I does not work when manuscript mode is selected. The non working example is also posted.

Comment: @AlanMunn I had previously found the page you're referring me too, but no answers there yet.

Comment: @user38333 I understand there's no answer there, but there's a lot more information pointed to in that question (and in the `apa6` documentation.)  Have you tried what the docs tell you to do? (Clearly from your `apa6` example document the answer seems to be "no".)

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes I have briefly, but I'll have another look.

Answer (score 2):

`tabu` unfortunately makes lots of definitions that make it incompatible with other packages. The underlying `longtable` code works without error on your example file.

[image]

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\shorttitle{zz}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{ccc} 
\caption{test} \\
\hline
Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
\hline
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\ 
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3  \\
    \hline

\end{longtable} % line 36
\end{landscape}    % line 37

\end{document}
```